# Edit : How to change this code into LINQ-expression

Tags: c#, linq, loops, foreach, linq-expressions

First of all, sorry if my question will confuse you. Well, I'm still a rocky about this programming in c#.

I am using the code below:

```
foreach (var schedule in schedules)
{
      if(schedule.SupplierId != Guid.Empty)
      {
          var supplier = db.Suppliers.Find(schedule.SupplierId);
          schedule.CompanyName = supplier.CompanyName;
      }
      if(schedule.CustomerId != Guid.Empty)
      {
          var customer = db.Customers.Find(schedule.CustomerId);      
          schedule.CompanyName= customer.CompanyName;
      }
}
```

It works really well, but what if the company that I will have is about a thousand company, this looping will slow my program, how to change this code into LINQ-expression.

Please for your reply. Thank you.

Comment: You can update as and when a company decides its update, but regardless, each one of those companies will need to run this code so therefore the time taken will probably be the same (if not more time needed due to the individual method calls)

Comment: @DavidBrabant why did you remove part of the original code?

Comment: Two blocks were exact duplicates. Thought that was an error. Was I wrong?

Comment: I've put it back in.. David, it contains info about customers instead and I suspect the OP is looking for a way to rewrite this.

Comment: Yep. I was. Sorry for that.

Comment: what kind of ORM mapper are you using? you can easily do it with a single query, using a join, or multiple selects.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a good way to do this in the client. There are some tools out there to do a mass update on EF, but I would suggest to run just a query to do this, if you need to do this at all. It seems you are updating a field which is just related, but in fact belongs to another entity. You shouldn't do that, since it means updating the one will leave the other invalid.

Answer (score 0):

What Patrick mentioned is absolutely right from an architectural point of view. In my understanding `CompanyName` belongs somewhere else, unless this entity is a "read-only view"...which obviously is not. Now, if you can't afford to make a major change I would suggest you move this heavy processing off the main thread to a separate thread...if you can.

You can also load all suppliers and companies in memory rather than opening a database connection 1000 times to issue a lookup query. But, again, consider strongly moving this to a separate thread